# How would the world economy change if there was a Japanese Cancer Cure in the 1950s, selling for $1000 US a person?

Tags: economy

**How would the world economy change if there was a Japanese Cancer Cure in the 1950s, selling for $1000 US a person?**

The Cure has no side-effects.

For a person whose whole body mass is cancer cells, but is still alive... It takes 1 week of treatment. Shrink the treatment length accordingly with less cancer cells.

Assume that the Japanese is willing to sell it at the given price, without taking into account shipping fees.

Japan is the only manufacturer, and has unlimited supply.

Chemo-therapy and stuff working concurrently with the Cure extend the treatment length to become four times longer.

Stopping the Chemo. and stuff makes the Cure work as fast as before.

Explain how Japan, or a Japanese country has a monopoly on the Cancer Cure in any way you want...

Comment: Any particular reason for it being Japan?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe it would have a marked effect on the economy?  How much of an effect do you believe cancer has had on the life and behavior of humanity as a whole?

Comment: @HDE226868 - Not really... Just wanted Japan. Unless the effects would be substantially different if it was anywhere else.

Comment: @CortAmmon - I don't expect a massive impact, But I do want to see if I'll be proven wrong... ... A sister question about the social impacts of such a cure would be more interesting... I think...

Comment: Remember, patents only last a fixed time.  After that, the drug would be manufactured everywhere.  And probably before that in areas with reputations for less concern for those things.

Comment: What makes it only manufacturable in Japan? @GrandmasterB 's point about patents is true. There will need to be some thing that means it can only be made in one place. I would have suggested a special genetically modified bacteria, but 1950s

Comment: Antibiotics had a huge effect in curing previous deadly diseases such as syphilis but they didn't really go beyond that. However, I don't think a cure for cancer can be found in isolation without greater knowledge of the whole growth and aging process. Today we can crudely destroy cancerous tissue, but if we had the sort of cure mentioned by the OP that would entail more than just a cure for cancer. It would also open up the ability to fix all sorts of tissue damage and some degree of rejuvenation.

Comment: @GrandmasterB - Magic! *Waves Hands*

Comment: @WilSelwood - Magic! *Waves Hands*

Comment: @DaveHalsall - Magic! *Waves Hands*

Comment: I like the *basic* premise of the question, but I feel that handwaving each followup question so easily really detracts from interesting answers.

Comment: @Geobits - ... True... ... Having Japan as the sole manufacturer for the Cancer Cure, via magic is very... *silly*, I suppose. Although, I do wonder how the magic specifies Japan... ... Gonna reverse my stance on Magic... I think...

Comment: You don't need to patent the idea. Protect it via "trade secret" and never share the information needed to create the cure. That preserves the monopoly indefinitely.
But I don't think there will be much political or economic difference globally. Some small splashes or ripples in history, but no tsunami.

Answer (score 5):

You specified the 1950s, and that only Japan can supply it.

- Adjusted for inflation, we're talking about \$10000 in 2015 prices. Even that is "affordable" for patients in Western industrialized countries. It might be more of a factor in the Japanese economy at the time.
- For Japan, the 1950s were a period of [growth through rebuilding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_post-war_economic_miracle#Ikeda_administration_and_keiretsu). The export miracle would start a decade early. Does that mean it bottoms out a decade early, too?
- This cure would make Japanese pharmaceutical companies a household name. Instead of Sony and Mitsubishi, we'de think about that when we think Japan.
- If Japanese companies were thought to sell this pretty much 'at cost', they'd get a lot of international goodwill. If the price was seen as 'inflated' to whatever the market would bear, there might by hostility for monopolizing it.

Answer (score 2):

The Japanese company will at first have a monopoly and can set any price they want. 1000 can be seen as cheap or rapacious depending on how much it cost to produce. If people are told that they can cure cancer for 1000$, that is really cheap. So people will buy it, those who can afford it.

The company will get richer of course, will it be significant?

[The World health organization](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs297/en/) says that " cancers figure among the leading causes of morbidity and mortality worldwide, with approximately 14 million new cases and 8.2 million cancer related deaths in 2012." That is a big market. At 1000 USD, it's a revenue of 14 b with numbers of 2012, if all the 14 million new people with case of cancer decide to buy the product. That's a quarter of the revenues of [Pfizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfizer), a large pharmaceutic company.

The GDP of [Japan](http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2015/01/weodata/weorept.aspx?pr.x=23&pr.y=9&sy=2014&ey=2014&scsm=1&ssd=1&sort=country&ds=.&br=1&c=512%2C668%2C914%2C672%2C612%2C946%2C614%2C137%2C311%2C962%2C213%2C674%2C911%2C676%2C193%2C548%2C122%2C556%2C912%2C678%2C313%2C181%2C419%2C867%2C513%2C682%2C316%2C684%2C913%2C273%2C124%2C868%2C339%2C921%2C638%2C948%2C514%2C943%2C218%2C686%2C963%2C688%2C616%2C518%2C223%2C728%2C516%2C558%2C918%2C138%2C748%2C196%2C618%2C278%2C624%2C692%2C522%2C694%2C622%2C142%2C156%2C449%2C626%2C564%2C628%2C565%2C228%2C283%2C924%2C853%2C233%2C288%2C632%2C293%2C636%2C566%2C634%2C964%2C238%2C182%2C662%2C453%2C960%2C968%2C423%2C922%2C935%2C714%2C128%2C862%2C611%2C135%2C321%2C716%2C243%2C456%2C248%2C722%2C469%2C942%2C253%2C718%2C642%2C724%2C643%2C576%2C939%2C936%2C644%2C961%2C819%2C813%2C172%2C199%2C132%2C733%2C646%2C184%2C648%2C524%2C915%2C361%2C134%2C362%2C652%2C364%2C174%2C732%2C328%2C366%2C258%2C734%2C656%2C144%2C654%2C146%2C336%2C463%2C263%2C528%2C268%2C923%2C532%2C738%2C944%2C578%2C176%2C537%2C534%2C742%2C536%2C866%2C429%2C369%2C433%2C744%2C178%2C186%2C436%2C925%2C136%2C869%2C343%2C746%2C158%2C926%2C439%2C466%2C916%2C112%2C664%2C111%2C826%2C298%2C542%2C927%2C967%2C846%2C443%2C299%2C917%2C582%2C544%2C474%2C941%2C754%2C446%2C698%2C666&s=NGDPD&grp=0&a=) is 4 616 b in USD. So the added value is 0,003% of the total country's GDP, it's a small number. The company will become rich (relatively) but it won't benefit the economy as a whole.

The global impact might be more tangible. It's not possible to measure the real value of life but keeping people alive longer means more taxes (harsh but true). The average American earns an average of 40 000 per year. If someone dies at 40 while he could have worked til 60, that's 800 000$ that will never enter in the country's economy. That's just an example, but it shows how much the society lose when someone dies at a young age from an economic point of view

It also means less costs for the healthcare system. I don't have the numbers but curing cancer require a lot of care and it cost a lot. The product will cost 1000$ but that is a fraction of the price paid to fight cancer with other means. Government will save billions that they will be able to spend elsewhere.

Comment: You have some very good points, but economy is a complex thing. First, people could have cancer more than once. Those who were cured when they were 5 could get it again later. People would generally live longer, which increase the pensions spending, and probably healthcare spending: after a given age, most people have some pain somewhere (legs, eyes, backs, etc.) which require medecine. So the money you saved on cancer treatment would be easily spent on surviving people.

Comment: Another point, of course, is that now, cancer is one of the main causes of death. But back in 1950, there were plenty more.

Comment: " If someone dies at 40 while he could have worked til 60, that's 800 000$ that will never enter in the country's economy." Hate to sound morbid but if someone dies at 60 when he could have been drawing a state pension (not to mention health care, etc.) till he was 80 then he is saving the country money...

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 major areas it would affect.

1. Health care.  It would significantly reduce the cost of health care as a cure for any cancer has a set amount with a max.  Cancer mediation and research is a HUGE part of our economy and our health care system.
2. This would increase the number of people surviving to older ages.  This would mean our population would increase faster putting more pressure on our resources.  More pressure of course raises prices.
3. Japan would become THE world power (or at least the seat of it) or if the secret gets out and you don't need special people to create the cure, then it will be the center of war for control of this most valuable resource.  If who controls Japan doesn't like what you are doing they can refuse to sell the cure to you holding it for ransom from your country.

If they keep the supply limited then there will likely not be much for second markets, and any black market cure will be astronomical in price, since it is basically taking someone elses cure for your own.  Who ever controls the Japanese cure will ultimately control the world.  Since if the citizens of a country are denied the cure, they will rise up, either blame their government and get a new one or try to go to war to 'take' their 'fair' share.  Of course any attempt at controlling Japan will result in other countries trying to stop it or else their supply might be cut off.  It will be an interesting house of cards keeping everything balanced.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think this would have much of an impact on the world economy, honestly.  Statistically speaking, cancer mostly afflicts people who are retired anyway, and if the cancer didn't kill them the heart disease would just get them a couple of years later.

It might be an economic windfall for as long as the patent lasts.  But that windfall might not be very long or very big, really.  The only significant population who could really afford a treatment at that price point right after World War II would be the United States, and, through some nefarious legal machinations, they might simply deny the Japanese any intellectual property rights, effectively seizing this miraculous cure as the spoils of war.  To be honest, I'm not sure they'd even be violating any international laws, as I don't know whether there *was* very much in the way of international IP law in those days.

In the final equation, I think that far and away the most prevalent effect for society at large would be on **the number of smokers**.  Everyone, everywhere, smoked in the 1950s.  The only reason smoking has dropped off in developed countries in recent decades is because the smokers themselves were dropping off, that is, dying of cancer.  Today, only a relatively few teenage morons start smoking, because most don't want to cough up a cupful of black phlegm like Grandpa Joe did right before they took him to the hospital for the last time.  But if, for the last 60 years, there had been a sure and relatively affordable cure for lung cancer, rest assured that every office and restaurant across the land would be filled with a cloud of gray-blue cigarette smoke.

Comment: Smoking also causes heart disease.  An easy cure for cancer might encourage reducing other major causes of death, such as heart disease.

Answer (score 1):

1950s Japan is a very very meanly picked location and time! You have world war 2 ended with 2 nuclear bombs dropped on Japan, claiming millions of their civilians. And then Japan develops this cancer cure which works certainly. There could only have been few comebacks harder than that.

1- First thing, if westerners can *reverse engineer* the drug/treatment and find out how it works, they would quickly do that and come up with another brand name of their own. And patenting the stuff won't stop them anyway. Western regulations were set up to protect western interests, so nobody would give two pence to a Japanese patent if they really wanted it. More so, when the country is a war-loser with a shattered economy. If westerners can accomplish finding the active ingredients and preparing them, they will do that and after the initial economic boom (depending on the number of cancer patients who decide to get Japanese treatment) the revenue would stay within the western countries.

2- If copying the treatment is not possible, all the revenue for cancer treatment would practically shift towards Japan. Now if cancer keeps proliferating during history as it has, Japan would be making handsome profits as time continued. Assuming that the treatment for one person is sold for 1000\$, we need to know much expenses does preparing the cure incur. If each treatment (for one person) provides with \$700 profit (\$300 cost), it would mean that Japan would be making ~3-4 million dollars of revenue during 60s with that cure. Notice that the cost of the treatment would keep most of the world population off of it as it is too high for 95% people of Asia, Africa and South America.

3- If copying the treatment is not possible and the Japanese treatment works like magic, the amount of revenue generated by the treatment would increase geometrically (by multiples). While estimating the amount of revenue generated is not precisely or accurately possible, it can be safely stated that the revenue would increase because a) the number of cancer victims has been increasing proportionally since 50s and b) the annual income of people living in the west has been increasing since 50s.

**Conclusion**

While it cannot be determined as to what extent this would affect world economy, it is obvious that you are siphoning some of the world money (most of which comes from north-western nations) to Japan. The amount of this money would keep on increasing as the number of cancer patients increases and more people can afford the treatment. This means that Japan's electronic revolution (production and export of electronic equipment) can be kick-started 10-15 earlier than it did. It is too complex to calculate how world economy would have changed in response to that.

We can safely assume that Japan would be a major player in world economy by 2020 and any fluctuations in Japanese market would have a small, but noticeable effect on the world economy.